# What are some of the best automated web QA tools out there?

Tags: automated-tests

**Issue**
We have a series of websites built in ASP.NET that we deploy frequently. Due to the lack of a QA team, we are unable to test the functionality and load of every web page within the site.

**Question**
What are some of the top tools for doing QA testing. The tool should include some basic functionality, such as: Notifying parties when unexpected results occur. Expected results should be configurable (i.e. Hit web page A, if the response doesn't have the string, "My intranet portal" in it, notify the appropriate parties).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. It's great that it is also open source. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try [TestPla](http://testplan.brainbrain.net/)n. I've used it to setup very complex and simple monitoring. It hooks into alert systems well and can be easily scheduled with cron or other tools. Basic tests are extremely easy to write.